# What does this block of code mean in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

```
var post = _.extend(_.pick(postAttributes, 'url', 'title', 'message'), {
    userId: user._id,
    author: user.username,
    submitted: new Date().getTime()
});
```

I'm following book "Discover Meteor" and they don't really explain this block of code. What exactly does it mean?

Comment: Read the [Underscore documentation](http://underscorejs.org/)

Answer (score 1):

`_.pick` creates a new object and takes a set of property names to copy from the old object. In this case, the "old object" is `postAttributes` and the properties to copy from it are `url`, `title`, `message`.

`_.extend` allows you to add properties to a target object. In this case, the target object is the resulting object from `_.pick`.

The result of it all becomes the object assigned to `post`.

<sub>"Copy" in pick isn't really copy. Primitives are copied. Objects are referenced, not copied. The operation is a shallow copy, and not deep for both `_.pick` and `_.extend`.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

It returns an object by abstracting `url, title, message` properties from `postAttributes` and extends with `userId, author, submitted` properties. `_` is the reference of [Underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org) library.